# Taking export backup of a database only upto certain date

Tags: oracle10g, export, database-backups

I have an oracle database(10 g edition). I want to take the export backup of the database upto some particular date. The backup should contain all the upto that specific date. Is there any way to perform the operation?

Comment: How are you defining the date? Do you have a column that tracks when something was added into the database? Do you never delete anything or are you wanting to grab the data as it existed at a date in the past without any reference to what the data might have looked like on that date?

Comment: There is no column to track whether something is added to the database. But some tables are there where logs are there to track on which date that particular data was added or modified. And yes, I want to capture the data the way you said.